# User Input Validation Using Character Array in C++

Tags: c++, validation, user-input

I am creating a c++ program to validate book ID using function in c++. The program must return 1 if the input is valid and 0 if the input is invalid. INPUT Pattern: "123-AB-12345" This will be considered as a valid input. The valid input is: (a) Total characters must be 12 (b) First three characters must be integers from 1 to 9 each. (c) 4th and 7th characters must be hiphen "-". (d) Last 5 characters must be integers from 1 to 9 each.

I tried the following way but I am not getting the desired answer. Need help plz

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isValidBookId(char bookId[13]);
int main()
{
    char book[13];
    cin.getline(book,12);
    bool id = isValidBookId(book);
    cout<<id;
}
bool isValidBookId(char bookId[13])
{
    int i;
    bool check1,check2,check3,check4,check5,check6;
    check1=check2=check3=check4=check5=true;
    if(bookId[12]=='\0'){
        check1=true;
    }       
    if(bookId[3]=='-')
    {
        check2=true;
    }
    if(bookId[6]=='-')
    {
        check3=true;
    }
    for(i=0; i<3;i++){
        if(bookId[i]>=0 || bookId[i]<=9)
        {
            check4=true;
        }
    }
    if(bookId[i]>= 'A' || bookId[i]<= 'Z')
    {
        check5=true;
    }
    for(i=7; i<12; i++)
    {
        if(bookId[i]>=0 || bookId[i]<=9)
        {
            check6=true;
        }
    }
    if(check1==true && check2==true && check3==true && check4==true && check5==true && check6==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see which check fails? Why are you doing checks like `bookId[12] == '\0'` **inside** your for loop? The answer won't change. Also, you initialize all your checks to `true`, and never set any to `false`.

Comment: Oh, I just removed that for loop but even am not getting it. Result is  always 1. @ChrisMM
Further I used bookId[12]=='\0' to flag a null character at the end of char array(bookId[ ]) so that a user must enter only 12 characters( index 0 to 11 and at index 12 it is obviosly '\0' (null character)

Comment: You never initialize `check6`. If you use its uninitialized and indeterminate value then you have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On another note, if you have `if (some_condition) return true; else return false;` that's exactly equal to `return some_condition;`.

Comment: I also recommend that you check out the [character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification), like for example [`std::isalnum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum).

Comment: Obligatory: you should (almost) never use char arrays in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few errors that you have in your code.

First, you initialize all your checks to `true`, and never set anything to `false`, so the answer will always be `true`. Realistically, you want to initialize them all to `false`, and change to `true` when all the conditions are met, or assume `true`, and set to `false` when the condition is not met.

Second, your check for the values `0-9` is incorrect. You cannot compare `bookId[i]` to `0`, you want to compare it to the character `'0'`. Also note that the question you have also says `1-9` not `0-9`

Third, your check for `A-Z` is incorrect (note, this issue also applies to `0-9`). You're code basically says is `bookId[i]` greater than or equal to 'A' OR less than or equal to `Z`, which is **always** going to be `true`.

I've written your code below:

```
bool isValidBookId( char bookId[13] ) {

    if ( bookId[12] != '\0' )
        return false;
    if ( bookId[3] != '-' )
        return false;
    if ( bookId[6] != '-' )
        return false;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        if ( bookId[i] < '1' || bookId[i] > '9' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 4; i < 6; i++ ) {
        if ( bookId[i] < 'A' || bookId[i] > 'Z' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 7; i < 12; i++ ) {
        if ( bookId[i] < '1' || bookId[i] > '9' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This method doesn't require any Boolean variables. Instead, I assume `true` (the last `return` statement) and instead try to prove `false`. As soon as something is `false`, you can return without doing any other checks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the given code is in C-Style format, I would like to present 2 additional solutions in C++. I think the task is anyway to think about patterns and how these could be detected.

In my first solutions I just added more C++ elements. The 2nd solution should be the correct on.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

bool isValidBookId1(const std::string& bookId) {

    // Lambda to detect hyphen
    auto ishyphen = [](int i){ return static_cast<int>(i == '-');};

    // First check size of given string
    bool result{(bookId.size() == 12)};

    // Define the position of the types
    std::vector<size_t> digitIndex{0,1,2,7,8,9,10,11};
    std::vector<size_t> letterIndex{4,5};
    std::vector<size_t> hyphenIndex{3,6};

    // Check types
    if (result) for (size_t index : digitIndex) result = result && std::isdigit(bookId[index]);
    if (result) for (size_t index : letterIndex) result = result && std::isupper(bookId[index]);
    if (result) for (size_t index : hyphenIndex) result = result && ishyphen(bookId[index]);

    // Return resulting value
    return result;
}

bool isValidBookId2(const std::string& bookId) {

    // Define pattern as a regex
    std::regex re{R"(\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{5})"}; 

    // Check, if the book id matches the pattern
    return std::regex_match(bookId, re);
}

int main()
{
    // Get input from user
    if (std::string line{}; std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << "Check for valid Book input 1: " << isValidBookId1(line) << "\n";
        std::cout << "Check for valid Book input 2: " << isValidBookId2(line) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```